# How do I copy user settings to a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I just got a new Windows 7 Home Premium x64 box at home and I'm going through the mundane task of setting everythig up how I like it.

Is there any easy way to copy all or some of my settings to other accounts on this PC?  It is a real pain to help other family members when all of their settings are different.  If I could just clone everything that would be fine or if you can only copy certain application settings that would be better than nothing.

I'm talking about things like:

- Windows Explorer: View file extensions, display columns, expand tree, and other settings
- Menu: small menu icons, auto hide, etc.
- Firefox settings and add-ons

Comment: Look at Microsoft's User State Migration tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used it extensively, but [this (Windows Easy Transfer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not trying to migrate users from xp/vista, just copy a win 7 user settings to another win 7 user.

Comment: Windows Easy Transfer will do what you need.  Hit the start button and type "Windows Easy Transfer" and follow the wizard.  It'll look for all profiles on the machine to work with.

Comment: As Rob said, it will allow you to migrate profiles within Windows 7 itself.

Comment: I just got a change to try this out ant it works. I was able to copy a user on a PC to a different user on the same PC. It works like a wizard, you say you are on the old PC, select the media to write the data to, select the users and items to copy, copy the data, restart wizard, say you are on new pc, and select new user ID and copy data.

Comment: Upvote for accepted solution?